# Where to find hive url, username and password?

Tags: python, hive, pyhive

In the command line, I can enter `hive` to get hive shell like:

```
hive>
```

then execute some queries.

Now I need write a python script with PyHive to execute some tasks, like:

```
conn = hive.Connection(host="10.111.22.11", port=10000, username="user1")
```

Where can I find the host, port, username, password used by shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just guesswork, but might help if you're willing to experiment. To find the url of HiveServer, from the hive> prompt, try `set hive.metastore.uris;` Output is something like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                        set                         |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| hive.metastore.uris=thrift://myuri.com:9083 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row selected (0.26 seconds)
```

Ignore thrift: and 9083. 10000 is the default port for Hive. Set up a Hive user with a password. In Hive 3, user permissions can be based on HDFS access control. [This doc](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/securing-hive/content/hive_sba_permissions_model.html) might help.

Comment: thanks, I have multiple `hive.metastore.uris`, which should I use?

Comment: For upgrades, I've heard you should use the first metastore in the list, but don't think it matters in your case. I think multiple metastores are just replications for failover (see https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/fault-tolerance/content/use_cases_and_failover_scenarios.html). Good luck.

Comment: see also https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Metastore+3.0+Administration

Comment: what would be host in this case. host="hive.metastore.uris=//myuri.com".?

Comment: The Hive metastore host's fully qualified domain name in this example is myuri.com. I think the python conn = hive.Connection(host=... accepts an IP address or the FQDN of the Hive metastore host.